# Prevent unlist to drop NULL values

Tags: list, r, null

I have a vector of lists and I use `unlist` on them. Some of the elements in the vectors are `NULL` and `unlist` seems to be dropping them.

How can I prevent this?

Here's a simple (non) working example showing this *unwanted feature* of `unlist`

```
a = c(list("p1"=2, "p2"=5), 
      list("p1"=3, "p2"=4), 
      list("p1"=NULL, "p2"=NULL), 
      list("p1"=4, "p2"=5))
unlist(a)
 p1 p2 p1 p2 p1 p2 
 2  5  3  4  4  5
```

Comment: It is confusing that `unlist` doesn't give any warning for `NULL` values and just drops them. I think would be useful information to throw an informative warning about NULLs. Especially that you can use further the results and some recycling behavior of the vectors might take place and one ends up with unexpected "correct' results, spinning around in circles trying to debug things while struggling to keep their sanity in balance :D

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The issue here is that you can't have `NULL` in the middle of a vector. For example:

```
> c(1,NULL,3)
[1] 1 3
```

You can have NA in the middle though. You could could convert it to character and then back to numeric, which automatically converts the NULL values to NA (with a warning):

```
> b <- as.numeric(as.character(a))
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```

then put the names back in, because they've been dropped by the previous operation:

```
> names(b) <- names(a)
> b
p1 p2 p1 p2 p1 p2 p1 p2 
2  5  3  4 NA NA  4  5 `
```

Comment: On 3.2.2, it looks like as.numeric(as.character(NULL)) returns numeric(0). A new approach might be to use lapply(b, function(x) ifelse(is.null(x), NA, x))

Comment: For the approach suggested by @cylondude, substitute sapply for lapply (or use lapply with simplify = TRUE) to get a vector instead of a list.

Answer (score 69):

In this case (one level depth list) this should works too:

```
a[sapply(a, is.null)] <- NA
unlist(a)
# p1 p2 p1 p2 p1 p2 p1 p2 
#  2  5  3  4 NA NA  4  5
```

Comment: a[sapply(a, function(x) length(x)==0L)] <- NA

Comment: Thanks @Ferroao, that worked for me, but is.null did not.

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with a long complex JSON with several levels you should give this a try:

I extracted game log data from nba.com/stats web site. The problem is, some players have a NULL value for 3 point free throws (mostly centers) and jsonlite::fromJSON seems to handle NULL values very well:

```
#### Player game logs URL: one record per player per game played ####
gameLogsURL <- paste("http://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguegamelog?Counter=1000&Direction=DESC&LeagueID=00&PlayerOrTeam=P&Season=2016-17&SeasonType=Regular+Season&Sorter=PTS")

#### Import game logs data from JSON ####
# use jsonlite::fromJSON to handle NULL values
gameLogsData <- jsonlite::fromJSON(gameLogsURL, simplifyDataFrame = TRUE)
# Save into a data frame and add column names
gameLogs <- data.frame(gameLogsData$resultSets$rowSet)
colnames(gameLogs) <- gameLogsData$resultSets$headers[[1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

A `tidyverse` solution using `purrr`

```
a <- map(a, ~ifelse(is.null(.x), NA, .x))
a %>% unlist()
```

Or if you want to do everything at once:

```
map_vec(a, ~ifelse(is.null(.x), NA, .x))
```

Answer (score -4):

The correct way to indicate a missing value is NA (not NULL). Here is another version that is working:

```
   a = c(list("p1"=2, "p2"=5),
      list("p1"=3, "p2"=4),
      list("p1"=NA, "p2"=NA),
      list("p1"=4, "p2"=5))
  unlist(a)

p1 p2 p1 p2 p1 p2 p1 p2 
 2  5  3  4 NA NA  4  5
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Obviously I do not define the list by hand, it is returned by a function.
Anyway changing the NULLs to NA before `unlist` seemed to do the trick.

Comment: @nico If it's your function then you might consider rewriting it to return `NA` instead of `NULL`. take a look on help pages to `NA` and `NULL` to see differences between this two objects.

Comment: @Marek: No, it actually is a list returned by applying `coef` on a list of objects returned by `nls`. Some of these objects are NULL and `coef(NULL)` returns `NULL`...