# Convert string of integer sequence to integer sequence

Tags: r, char, integer

Suppose I have the element

```
    x <- "1:4"
```

I try to convert x into a sequence as follow

```
    as.integer(x)
    [1] NA
    Warning message:
    NAs introduced by coercion
```

How can I get an integer sequence beginning from a string?

Comment: ` eval(parse(text = "1:4"))`

Answer (score 0):

When you type `x <- "1:4"` you are not creating a string of 4 characters 1, 2, 3, and 4. You are creating a string that's simply "1:4". Naturally when you convert this to numbers, it makes no sense. Hence you want `x <- 1:4`.

Comment: here the reason of my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41595942/convert-list-of-list-to-a-coerced-dataframe?noredirect=1#comment70395772_41595942

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Gaurav beat me to this.

Firstly, `x<-"1:4"` will be saved as "1:4"

```
x<-"1:4"
str(x)
    chr "1:4"
```

Therefore it cannot be turned into an integer, it is merely saved as characters. You first need to remove the "" from the x<-"1:4" at which point you'll by default get a list of 4 integers 1:4 :

```
x<-1:4
str(x)
   int [1:4] 1 2 3 4
```