# R: Using the unlist() function for a list that has some elements being integer(0)?

Tags: r

In R, I am calling `unlist` on a list to convert to a vector. However, some of my list elements are empty, and hence returns `integer(0)`. The `unlist()` function by default drops this. How can I return a vector that has `NA` where the list is empty? I have created a reproducible example:

```
> ex.list <- list()
> ex.list[[1]] <- integer(0)
> ex.list[[2]] <- c(1,2,3)
> ex.list
[[1]]
integer(0)

[[2]]
[1] 1 2 3

> unlist(ex.list)
[1] 1 2 3
```

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991514/prevent-unlist-to-drop-null-values

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A way of doing it is to use function `is.na<-`.

```
is.na(ex.list) <- lengths(ex.list) == 0

ex.list
#[[1]]
#[1] NA
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 1 2 3
```

Then you will have a `NA` where the list had a length of 0.

```
unlist(ex.list)
#[1] NA  1  2  3
```

Comment: Why does this work, although `is.na(ex.list)` yields `[1] FALSE FALSE` in the beginning? Do I miss something? The length 0 and NA issue puzzles me quite a lot in R...

Comment: @Christoph - `is.na<-` is a function. Type `\`is.na<-\`` and `\`is.na<-.default\`` at the console to see what it is doing.

Answer (score 3):

We can do an assignment based on the `length` of the `list` element i.e. if it is equal to 0, assign as `NA`

```
ex.list[lengths(ex.list)==0] <- NA
ex.list
#[[1]]
#[1] NA

#[[2]]
#[1] 1 2 3
```

Comment: And of course you can do it all in one step if you don't want to change the original `ex.list` - `unlist(replace(ex.list, lengths(ex.list)==0, NA))`

Answer (score 2):

You could also try the one-liner

```
unlist(lapply(ex.list, function (x) ifelse(length (x) > 0, x, NA)))
```